# What are good plants to use in a container-based winter garden?

Tags: containers, plant-recommendations, winter-gardening, fall-gardening

I live in an apartment that has a small outdoor patio and I'm looking to create a little container garden this autumn/winter. I'm located in the US (hardiness zone is 7) and I'm looking for ideas (plants) that might work well in this environment.

The containers are of an undetermined size at this point. The deck patio area we have to work with is about 4 x 3 (ft.) and is facing west. We are looking to plant in late autumn and have the garden through the winter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, I would recommend you plant anytime from now until mid Autumn (Fall). **Why?**

- Will give the plants a little more time to establish themselves in the containers before Winter arrives.

Second, below is some "general" container information that I believe might prove helpful:

- [Recipe for a long-lasting, fast draining container soil mix with good aeration](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/q/721/394)
- [Sustainable alternatives to peat for potting compost](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/q/1482/394)
- [What should I do about standing water in potted plant?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/q/1184/394)

Now to answer your question, below are few plants that I believe would work well given your requirements:

- **Part shade to full shade**

  - [Hellebore *Helleborus orientalis*](http://www.mobot.org/gardeninghelp/plantfinder/plant.asp?code=D100)
  - [Hellebore *Helleborus* 'Winter Joy Bouquet'](http://www.mobot.org/gardeninghelp/plantfinder/plant.asp?code=Y990)
  - [Christmas rose *Helleborus* 'Walhelivor' Ivory Prince](http://www.mobot.org/gardeninghelp/plantfinder/plant.asp?code=D652)
  - [Christmas fern *Polystichum acrostichoides*](http://www.mobot.org/gardeninghelp/plantfinder/plant.asp?code=A710)
- **Full sun to part shade**

  - [Tussock sedge *Carex stricta*](http://www.mobot.org/gardeninghelp/plantfinder/plant.asp?code=D584)
  - [Leatherleaf sedge *Carex buchananii*](http://www.mobot.org/gardeninghelp/plantfinder/plant.asp?code=J630)
  - [Winter heath *Erica carnea* 'Springwood Pink'](http://www.mobot.org/gardeninghelp/plantfinder/plant.asp?code=C274)
  - [Japanese boxwood *Buxus microphylla var. japonica* 'Morris Midget'](http://www.mobot.org/gardeninghelp/plantfinder/plant.asp?code=B770)
  - [Japanese holly *Ilex crenata* 'Sky Pencil'](http://www.mobot.org/gardeninghelp/plantfinder/plant.asp?code=V890)

---

*Good luck! And enjoy your Winter garden.*